# How to hardcode Zebra label substitution in this script?

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I am familiar with some label formatting but having an issue with this task.  In the image, there is a table that should populate in the middle area when there are locations (up to 10), with columns for location, size description, TOT To SER, Description, and UN Number.  I need to hardcode some values so I can see them in a ZPL viewer and mess with the formatting.  How can I hardcode those values so I see atleast the row for location_1 with table borders?  Thanks in advance for any help! I know the code is long but I think I just need to hardcode the location_1 body the middle of the code to anything.  Like LOCATIONXYZ

```
#parse("version.vm")
#if ($PrintMode == "Bartender" || $PrintMode == "MarkMagic")
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR2,2~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT

## crtncnts.vm - Carton Content Label (6x8 inches 203 dpi)
## in:
##      /appli/manh/wms/profile-root/runtime/data/labels/ZE1
##      /appli/manh/wms/distribution/data/labels/ZE1
## version:
^FX crtncnts.vm - 2017/09/07 - v4.1 ^FS
## change:
## 2017/08/29 - v3.1 - add comments and versionning
## 2017/09/06 - v3.2 - change of date format
## 2017/09/07 - v4.0 - suppression of "origin" column + set "UN Number" column to cust_sku_n
## 2017/09/07 - v4.1 - use of $vendor_item_nbr_n instead of $cust_sku_n in "UN Number" column

## Label size for 203 dpi (with 6+6 margin space)
^PW1224
^LL1632

## Framework (origin is 33x33)
^FO33,33^GB1167,1567,7^FS   ^FX Global frame ^FS
^FO160,33^GB220,527,7^FS    ^FX Bloc 4 (right) ^FS
^FO160,553^GB220,527,7^FS   ^FX Bloc 3 (middle) ^FS
^FO160,1073^GB220,527,7^FS  ^FX Bloc 2 (left) ^FS
^FO953,33^GB247,1567,7^FS   ^FX Bloc 6 (footer) ^FS

## Blocs in read direction

## Bloc 1 (header)
^FT120,547^A0B,67,60^FB487,1,0,R^FD$!{carton_nbr}^FS
^FT120,1073^A0B,67,60^FB520,1,0,C^FDPicking List^FS
^FT107,1573^A0B,33,31^FC%,@,*^FD%m/%d/%Y  %H:%M:%S^FS

## Bloc 2 (left)
^FT200,1573^A0B,33,31^FDCustomer:^FS
^FT247,1553^A0B,33,31^FD$!{d_facility_name}^FS
#set ($Max_NbChar=31) #if ($!{ship_to_name.length()} > $Max_NbChar) #set ($ship_to_name=$ship_to_name.substring(0,$Max_NbChar)) #end
^FT287,1553^A0B,33,31^FD$!{ship_to_name}^FS

## Bloc 3 (middle)
^FT200,1053^A0B,33,31^FDConstituting a Parcel: $!{carton_type}^FS
#set ($Max_NbChar=14) #if ($!{orders_ref_field3.length()} > $Max_NbChar) #set ($orders_ref_field3=$orders_ref_field3.substring(0,$Max_NbChar))   
#end
^FT247,1053^A0B,33,31^FDType of Shipment: $!{orders_ref_field3}^FS

## Bloc 4 (right)
#set ($Max_NbChar=18) #if ($!{po_nbr.length()} > $Max_NbChar) #set ($po_nbr=$po_nbr.substring(0,$Max_NbChar)) #end
^FT200,540^A0B,33,31^FDOrder Number: $!{po_nbr}^FS
^FT247,540^A0B,33,31^FDDelivery Number: $!{distro_number}^FS
^FT333,520^BY3,3,73^BCB,,Y,N^FD>:$!{distro_number}^FS

## Bloc 5 (list): columns are ordered A to E in reading direction

## Bloc 5 (list): header framework (FWK)
#set($FWK_Offset_x=387)
#set($FWK_Offset_y_E=53)
#set($FWK_Offset_y_D=253)
#set($FWK_Offset_y_C=1013)
#set($FWK_Offset_y_B=1160)
#set($FWK_Offset_y_A=1373)
#set($FWK_Size_x=53)
#set($FWK_Size_y_E=203)
#set($FWK_Size_y_D=762)
#set($FWK_Size_y_C=149)
#set($FWK_Size_y_B=216)
#set($FWK_Size_y_A=209)
#set($FWK_Thickness=3)
^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_E ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_E,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_D ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_D,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_C ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_C,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_B ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_B,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_A ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_A,$FWK_Thickness ^FS

## Bloc 5 (list): header content (CNT)
#set($CNT_size_x=23)
#set($CNT_Size_y=21)
#set($CNT_Offset_y_E=240)
#set($CNT_Offset_y_D=999)
#set($CNT_Offset_y_C=1146)
#set($CNT_Offset_y_B=1360)
#set($CNT_Offset_y_A=1567)
#set($CNT_offset_x=420)
^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_E ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FDUN_Number^FS
^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_D ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FDDescription^FS
^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_C ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FDTOT TO SER^FS
^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_B ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FDSize Description^FS
^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_A ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FDLocation^FS

## Max number of character for each column (ordered A to E in reading direction)
#set($Max_NbChar_E=16)
#set($Max_NbChar_D=64)
#set($Max_NbChar_C=11)
#set($Max_NbChar_B=17)
#set($Max_NbChar_A=17)

## Shift between each line (Step)
#set($Step=51)

## Bloc 5 (list): line 1
#if ($location_1)
    #set($FWK_Offset_x=$FWK_Offset_x+$Step)
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_E ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_E,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_D ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_D,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_C ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_C,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_B ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_B,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_A ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_A,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    #set($CNT_offset_x=$CNT_offset_x+$Step)
    #if ($!{vendor_item_nbr_1.length()} > $Max_NbChar_E)    #set ($vendor_item_nbr_1=$vendor_item_nbr_1.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_E)) #end
    #if ($!{sku_desc_1.length()} > $Max_NbChar_D)           #set ($sku_desc_1=$sku_desc_1.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_D)) #end
    #if ($!{qty_1.length()} > $Max_NbChar_C)                #set ($qty_1=$qty_1.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_C)) #end
    #if ($!{dsp_sku_1.length()} > $Max_NbChar_B)            #set ($dsp_sku_1=$dsp_sku_1.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_B)) #end
    #if ($!{location_1.length()} > $Max_NbChar_A)           #set ($location_1=$location_1.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_A)) #end
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_E ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{vendor_item_nbr_1}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_D ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{sku_desc_1}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_C ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{qty_1}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_B ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{dsp_sku_1}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_A ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{location_1}^FS
#end

## Bloc 5 (list): line 2
#if ($location_2)
    #set($FWK_Offset_x=$FWK_Offset_x+$Step)
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_E ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_E,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_D ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_D,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_C ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_C,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_B ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_B,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_A ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_A,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    #set($CNT_offset_x=$CNT_offset_x+$Step)
    #if ($!{vendor_item_nbr_2.length()} > $Max_NbChar_E)    #set ($vendor_item_nbr_2=$vendor_item_nbr_2.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_E)) #end
    #if ($!{sku_desc_2.length()} > $Max_NbChar_D)           #set ($sku_desc_2=$sku_desc_2.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_D)) #end
    #if ($!{qty_2.length()} > $Max_NbChar_C)                #set ($qty_2=$qty_2.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_C)) #end
    #if ($!{dsp_sku_2.length()} > $Max_NbChar_B)            #set ($dsp_sku_2=$dsp_sku_2.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_B)) #end
    #if ($!{location_2.length()} > $Max_NbChar_A)           #set ($location_2=$location_2.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_A)) #end
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_E ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{vendor_item_nbr_2}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_D ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{sku_desc_2}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_C ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{qty_2}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_B ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{dsp_sku_2}^FS
^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_A ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{location_2}^FS
#end

## Bloc 5 (list): line 3
#if ($location_3)
    #set($FWK_Offset_x=$FWK_Offset_x+$Step)
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_E ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_E,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_D ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_D,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_C ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_C,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_B ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_B,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_A ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_A,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    #set($CNT_offset_x=$CNT_offset_x+$Step)
    #if ($!{vendor_item_nbr_3.length()} > $Max_NbChar_E)    #set ($vendor_item_nbr_3=$vendor_item_nbr_3.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_E)) #end
    #if ($!{sku_desc_3.length()} > $Max_NbChar_D)           #set ($sku_desc_3=$sku_desc_3.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_D)) #end
    #if ($!{qty_3.length()} > $Max_NbChar_C)                #set ($qty_3=$qty_3.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_C)) #end
    #if ($!{dsp_sku_3.length()} > $Max_NbChar_B)            #set ($dsp_sku_3=$dsp_sku_3.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_B)) #end
    #if ($!{location_3.length()} > $Max_NbChar_A)           #set ($location_3=$location_3.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_A)) #end
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_E ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{vendor_item_nbr_3}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_D ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{sku_desc_3}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_C ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{qty_3}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_B ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{dsp_sku_3}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_A ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{location_3}^FS
#end

## Bloc 5 (list): line 4
#if ($location_4)
    #set($FWK_Offset_x=$FWK_Offset_x+$Step)
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_E ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_E,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_D ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_D,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_C ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_C,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_B ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_B,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_A ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_A,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    #set($CNT_offset_x=$CNT_offset_x+$Step)
    #if ($!{vendor_item_nbr_4.length()} > $Max_NbChar_E)    #set ($vendor_item_nbr_4=$vendor_item_nbr_4.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_E)) #end
    #if ($!{sku_desc_4.length()} > $Max_NbChar_D)           #set ($sku_desc_4=$sku_desc_4.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_D)) #end
    #if ($!{qty_4.length()} > $Max_NbChar_C)                #set ($qty_4=$qty_4.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_C)) #end
    #if ($!{dsp_sku_4.length()} > $Max_NbChar_B)            #set ($dsp_sku_4=$dsp_sku_4.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_B)) #end
    #if ($!{location_4.length()} > $Max_NbChar_A)           #set ($location_4=$location_4.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_A)) #end
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_E ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{vendor_item_nbr_4}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_D ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{sku_desc_4}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_C ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{qty_4}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_B ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{dsp_sku_4}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_A ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{location_4}^FS
#end

## Bloc 5 (list): line 5
#if ($location_5)
    #set($FWK_Offset_x=$FWK_Offset_x+$Step)
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_E ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_E,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_D ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_D,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_C ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_C,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_B ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_B,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_A ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_A,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    #set($CNT_offset_x=$CNT_offset_x+$Step)
    #if ($!{vendor_item_nbr_5.length()} > $Max_NbChar_E)    #set ($vendor_item_nbr_5=$vendor_item_nbr_5.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_E)) #end
    #if ($!{sku_desc_5.length()} > $Max_NbChar_D)           #set ($sku_desc_5=$sku_desc_5.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_D)) #end
    #if ($!{qty_5.length()} > $Max_NbChar_C)                #set ($qty_5=$qty_5.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_C)) #end
    #if ($!{dsp_sku_5.length()} > $Max_NbChar_B)            #set ($dsp_sku_5=$dsp_sku_5.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_B)) #end
    #if ($!{location_5.length()} > $Max_NbChar_A)           #set ($location_5=$location_5.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_A)) #end
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_E ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{vendor_item_nbr_5}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_D ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{sku_desc_5}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_C ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{qty_5}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_B ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{dsp_sku_5}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_A ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{location_5}^FS
#end

## Bloc 5 (list): line 6
#if ($location_6)
    #set($FWK_Offset_x=$FWK_Offset_x+$Step)
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_E ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_E,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_D ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_D,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_C ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_C,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_B ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_B,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_A ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_A,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    #set($CNT_offset_x=$CNT_offset_x+$Step)
    #if ($!{vendor_item_nbr_6.length()} > $Max_NbChar_E)    #set ($vendor_item_nbr_6=$vendor_item_nbr_6.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_E)) #end
    #if ($!{sku_desc_6.length()} > $Max_NbChar_D)           #set ($sku_desc_6=$sku_desc_6.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_D)) #end
    #if ($!{qty_6.length()} > $Max_NbChar_C)                #set ($qty_6=$qty_6.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_C)) #end
    #if ($!{dsp_sku_6.length()} > $Max_NbChar_B)            #set ($dsp_sku_6=$dsp_sku_6.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_B)) #end
    #if ($!{location_6.length()} > $Max_NbChar_A)           #set ($location_6=$location_6.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_A)) #end
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_E ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{vendor_item_nbr_6}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_D ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{sku_desc_6}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_C ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{qty_6}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_B ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{dsp_sku_6}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_A ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{location_6}^FS
#end

## Bloc 5 (list): line 7
#if ($location_7)
    #set($FWK_Offset_x=$FWK_Offset_x+$Step)
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_E ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_E,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_D ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_D,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_C ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_C,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_B ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_B,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_A ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_A,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    #set($CNT_offset_x=$CNT_offset_x+$Step)
    #if ($!{vendor_item_nbr_7.length()} > $Max_NbChar_E)    #set ($vendor_item_nbr_7=$vendor_item_nbr_7.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_E)) #end
    #if ($!{sku_desc_7.length()} > $Max_NbChar_D)           #set ($sku_desc_7=$sku_desc_7.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_D)) #end
    #if ($!{qty_7.length()} > $Max_NbChar_C)                #set ($qty_7=$qty_7.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_C)) #end
    #if ($!{dsp_sku_7.length()} > $Max_NbChar_B)            #set ($dsp_sku_7=$dsp_sku_7.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_B)) #end
    #if ($!{location_7.length()} > $Max_NbChar_A)           #set ($location_7=$location_7.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_A)) #end
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_E ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{vendor_item_nbr_7}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_D ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{sku_desc_7}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_C ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{qty_7}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_B ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{dsp_sku_7}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_A ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{location_7}^FS
#end

## Bloc 5 (list): line 8
#if ($location_8)
    #set($FWK_Offset_x=$FWK_Offset_x+$Step)
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_E ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_E,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_D ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_D,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_C ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_C,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_B ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_B,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_A ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_A,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    #set($CNT_offset_x=$CNT_offset_x+$Step)
    #if ($!{vendor_item_nbr_8.length()} > $Max_NbChar_E)    #set ($vendor_item_nbr_8=$vendor_item_nbr_8.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_E)) #end
    #if ($!{sku_desc_8.length()} > $Max_NbChar_D)           #set ($sku_desc_8=$sku_desc_8.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_D)) #end
    #if ($!{qty_8.length()} > $Max_NbChar_C)                #set ($qty_8=$qty_8.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_C)) #end
    #if ($!{dsp_sku_8.length()} > $Max_NbChar_B)            #set ($dsp_sku_8=$dsp_sku_8.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_B)) #end
    #if ($!{location_8.length()} > $Max_NbChar_A)           #set ($location_8=$location_8.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_A)) #end
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_E ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{vendor_item_nbr_8}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_D ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{sku_desc_8}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_C ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{qty_8}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_B ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{dsp_sku_8}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_A ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{location_8}^FS
#end

## Bloc 5 (list): line 9
#if ($location_9)
    #set($FWK_Offset_x=$FWK_Offset_x+$Step)
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_E ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_E,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_D ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_D,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_C ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_C,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_B ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_B,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_A ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_A,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    #set($CNT_offset_x=$CNT_offset_x+$Step)
    #if ($!{vendor_item_nbr_9.length()} > $Max_NbChar_E)    #set ($vendor_item_nbr_9=$vendor_item_nbr_9.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_E)) #end
    #if ($!{sku_desc_9.length()} > $Max_NbChar_D)           #set ($sku_desc_9=$sku_desc_9.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_D)) #end
    #if ($!{qty_9.length()} > $Max_NbChar_C)                #set ($qty_9=$qty_9.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_C)) #end
    #if ($!{dsp_sku_9.length()} > $Max_NbChar_B)            #set ($dsp_sku_9=$dsp_sku_9.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_B)) #end
    #if ($!{location_9.length()} > $Max_NbChar_A)           #set ($location_9=$location_9.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_A)) #end
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_E ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{vendor_item_nbr_9}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_D ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{sku_desc_9}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_C ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{qty_9}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_B ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{dsp_sku_9}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_A ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{location_9}^FS
#end

## Bloc 5 (list): line 10
#if ($location_10)
    #set($FWK_Offset_x=$FWK_Offset_x+$Step)
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_E ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_E,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_D ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_D,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_C ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_C,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_B ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_B,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    ^FO$FWK_Offset_x,$FWK_Offset_y_A ^GB$FWK_Size_x,$FWK_Size_y_A,$FWK_Thickness ^FS
    #set($CNT_offset_x=$CNT_offset_x+$Step)
    #if ($!{vendor_item_nbr_10.length()} > $Max_NbChar_E)   #set ($vendor_item_nbr_10=$vendor_item_nbr_10.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_E)) #end
    #if ($!{sku_desc_10.length()} > $Max_NbChar_D)          #set ($sku_desc_10=$sku_desc_10.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_D)) #end
    #if ($!{qty_10.length()} > $Max_NbChar_C)               #set ($qty_10=$qty_10.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_C)) #end
    #if ($!{dsp_sku_10.length()} > $Max_NbChar_B)           #set ($dsp_sku_10=$dsp_sku_10.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_B)) #end
    #if ($!{location_10.length()} > $Max_NbChar_A)          #set ($location_10=$location_10.substring(0,$Max_NbChar_A)) #end
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_E ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{vendor_item_nbr_10}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_D ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{sku_desc_10}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_C ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{qty_10}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_B ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{dsp_sku_10}^FS
    ^FT$CNT_offset_x,$CNT_Offset_y_A ^A0B,$CNT_size_x,$CNT_Size_y ^FD$!{location_10}^FS
#end

## Bloc 6 (footer)
^FT993,1573^A0B,33,31^FDParcel #:^FS
^FT993,1453^A0B,33,31^FD$!{carton_nbr}^FS
^FT1087,1453^BY4,3,87^BCB,,Y,N^FD>:$!{carton_nbr}^FS
^FT1087,540^A0B,33,31^FDTheoretical weight: $!{Est_Wt} KgG^FS
^FT1167,1573^A0B,33,31^FDYour parcel was thoughtfully prepared by:^FS

^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ
#end
#*
__START_FIELD_LIST_BARTENDER__
carton_nbr
carton_type
current_date
current_time
d_facility_name
distro_nbr
distro_number
dsp_sku_1
dsp_sku_2
dsp_sku_3
dsp_sku_4
dsp_sku_5
dsp_sku_6
dsp_sku_7
dsp_sku_8
dsp_sku_9
dsp_sku_10
location_1
location_2
location_3
location_4
location_5
location_6
location_7
location_8
location_9
location_10
orders_ref_field3
po_nbr
qty_1
qty_2
qty_3
qty_4
qty_5
qty_6
qty_7
qty_8
qty_9
qty_10
ship_to_name
sku_desc_1
    sku_desc_2
sku_desc_3
sku_desc_4
sku_desc_5
    sku_desc_6
sku_desc_7
sku_desc_8
sku_desc_9
sku_desc_10
vendor_item_nbr_1
vendor_item_nbr_2
vendor_item_nbr_3
vendor_item_nbr_4
vendor_item_nbr_5
vendor_item_nbr_6
vendor_item_nbr_7
vendor_item_nbr_8
vendor_item_nbr_9
vendor_item_nbr_10
__END_FIELD_LIST_BARTENDER__
*#
```

[Label Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyGUk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Just take the code you have, replace all the variables with actual values, and then it should work.  Mess with it till you get what you want. Then replace all the hard coded values with the variables again.

All if the ZPL commands the printer reads start with ^XYa,b,c, where ^ is the command prefix, XY would be the command, and abc would be different variables. You can look up the ^XY commands in the ZPL guide from Zebra. Things like "$CNT_offset_x" need to be replace with numbers. And "$!{vendor_item_nbr_1}" with text.

You'd do yourself a HUGE favor if you made one "line" section, and put that in a loop, rather than 10 distinct line sections. Then in the loop, you could take the line height, and multiply that by the line number, and add the starting position. Use that for all the vertical positioning pixel counts. So much easier than positioning every variable. Then if you need to change something, you can change it once, rather than 10 times.

Comment: Actually, looks like you're using bartender. Not sure how that works. Maybe you cant do loops. If I was you, I'd skip the third party software. It's only a limitation.

Comment: Thanks @EdHayes3 but I still cannot get it to hardcode.  Even if I replace every ($location_1) with "LOCATIONXYZ", the table in the middle will not show.  Could you please show me where it needs to be hardcodes in that location_1 #if statement to populate?

Comment: All if the ZPL commands the printer reads start with ^XYa,b,c, where ^ is the command prefix, XY would be the command, and abc would be different variables. You can look up the ^XY commands in the ZPL guide from Zebra. Things like "$CNT_offset_x" need to be replace with numbers. And "$!{vendor_item_nbr_1}" with text.

Comment: This worked perfectly and allows me to begin formatting.  Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @BigTuna89, you're welcome. I added my last comment to the answer. Please mark the answer as accepted. Thanks!